# Can $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+e^{2\pi i n\tau})$ be expressed in terms of the Euler Phi Function?

Tags: special-functions, infinite-product, modular-forms

I am wondering if $$(-e^{2\pi i \tau},e^{2\pi i \tau})_\infty=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+e^{2\pi i n\tau})$$ can be expressed in terms of [Euler's Phi Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you think it can?

Comment: @Wojowu It looks very similar to the Phi function and I believe it may be expressible in terms of a ratio of Phi functions.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was thinking of totient function - I should've clicked the link first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that
$$1+e^{2\pi i n\tau}=\frac{1-(e^{4\pi i\tau})^n}{1-(e^{2\pi i\tau})^n}$$
(this is just $1+a=\frac{1-a^2}{1-a}$). Hence
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+e^{2\pi i n\tau})=\frac{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-(e^{4\pi i\tau})^n)}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-(e^{2\pi i\tau})^n)}=\frac{\phi(e^{4\pi i\tau})}{\phi(e^{2\pi i\tau})}=\frac{\phi(q^2)}{\phi(q)}$$
for $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$.